# If a sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ is such that $a_1a_2=1, a_2a_3=2, \ldots$ and $\lim\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1.$ Then find $|a_1|.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here since $\lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1.$ So no definite conclusion can be made about the nature of the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$.

So how can I can proceed to find the value of $a_1$ from the relation: $a_ka_{k+1}=k,$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$ ?

Please suggest something..

Comment: I'd take $\log$ first.

Comment: To understand why this question is interesting, guess a value, say $a_{1} = 1$.  Then, $a_{2} = 1$, $a_{3}=2$, $a_{4}=3/2$, $a_{5}=8/3$, $a_{6}=15/8$, $a_{7}=16/5$ $\ldots$  It's not obvious that the ratios converge to $1$.  Perhaps the value for $a_{1}$ that results in a ratio converging to $1$ is unique? Otherwise, there might be a persistent oscillation between evens and odds.

Comment: Write $a_2,a_3,a_4,...$ in terms of $a_1$

Comment: @Sherwin Lott, I don't have the answer now. Found the question in a magazine. May be they will publish the answers to the various problems next month.

Comment: @Sherwin Lott, yes I tried that but that gives us a recurrence relation and I don't know what the actual answer is. Also they have asked to find $|a_1|.$ So I wasn't quite sure how to deal with it!!?

Comment: @Alexy Burden, what's the core idea or intuition behind it?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get a uniqueness statement: suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two sequences satisfying the givens. Notice that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are never zero, because of the condition on products. Let $c_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Then we have $c_nc_{n+1} = 1$ and $\lim \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=1$. If we let $c_1=x$, the first condition clearly specifies the whole sequence as

\begin{align*}
c_1=x && c_2=\frac{1}{x} && c_3 = x && c_4 = \frac{1}{x} && \ldots  
\end{align*}

The condition on the ratios is then that

\begin{align*}
x^2, \frac{1}{x^2}, x^2, \frac{1}{x}^2, \ldots \to 1 
\end{align*}

which gives $x= \pm 1$. So, either $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$, or else $a_n = -b_n$ for all $n$. Thus the solution, if it exists, is unique up to multiplying the whole sequence by $-1$ (which clearly preserves the given conditions).

Comment: Thank you sir.. After seeing Sherwin Lott sir's comment, I realized uniqueness of the sequence up to multiplying the same by $-1$, intuitively. But your answer makes it crystal clear.. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_{2k+1} = \frac{2k}{2k-1}a_{2k-1} = ... = a_1\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j}{2j-1} $  and $a_{2k+2} = a_2 \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j+1}{2j} = \frac{1}{a_1}\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j+1}{2j}$

By looking at the subsequence:
$$ 1 = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{2k+1}}{a_{2k+2}} = a_1^2\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j}{2j-1}}{\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j+1}{2j}} = a_1^2 \lim_{k \to \infty} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(2j)(2j)}{(2j+1)(2j-1)} = a_1^2 \frac{\pi}{2} $$
Where we used Wallis Formula for $\pi$:
$$ \prod_{j=1}^\infty \frac{4j^2}{(2j-1)(2j+1)} = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Similarly $$ 1 = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{2k+2}}{a_{2k+3}} = \frac{1}{a_1^2} \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2k+1}{2k+2} \cdot\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(2j+1)(2j-1)}{(2j)(2j)} = \frac{1}{a_1^2}\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Hence in both cases (and subsequences $(2k)_{k \in \mathbb N},(2k+1)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ cover whole sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$), we get condition $$a_1^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$$ so we get the value of $a_1$ up to the sign, that is: $$ |a_1| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

And Mike F already showed that $|a_1|$ is unique

Comment: Thank you sir... Just like Mike F sir, if I first show the uniqueness of the sequence up to multiplying the whole sequence by $-1$, then according to me, we don't need to show that from $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{2k+2}}{a_{2k+3}}=1$$ also we get $a_1^2=\frac2π.$ Isn't it?

Comment: Mike showed that the value is unique up to the sign. It does not guarantee existence. Neither showing that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{2k+1}}{a_{2k+2}} = 1$ iff $a_1^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$ does not tell us that  $a_1^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1$. We know only that necessary condition is $a_1^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$. It might happen that such sequence is not well defined, so we need to take care of the remaining subsequence.

Comment: Oh okk.. Got it sir. Thanks..